How to show persistent notification with icon buttons in flutter
I am developing a simple flashlight app in flutter. I need to show the persistent notification like this. With icon buttons (Not text buttons).

When user click on the torch icon, The flashlight of the mobile need
to turn on or off.

When user click on the Screen button App need to open.



